# how to convert audio file into text using CMU Sphinx

Tags: java, cmusphinx, audio-converter

I am trying to convert an audio file, below is my code

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Loading models...");

                Configuration configuration = new Configuration();

                // Load model from the jar
                configuration.setAcousticModelPath("resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz");
                configuration.setDictionaryPath("resource:/WSJ_8gau_13dCep_16k_40mel_130Hz_6800Hz/dict/cmudict.0.6d");        
                configuration.setLanguageModelPath("models/language/en-us.lm.dmp");

                StreamSpeechRecognizer recognizer = new StreamSpeechRecognizer(configuration);


                URL audioUrl = new URL("file:///C:/Sound1.wav");
                recognizer.startRecognition(audioUrl.openStream());

                SpeechResult result;

                while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null) {
                    System.out.format("Hypothesis: %s\n",
                                      result.getHypothesis());
                }

                System.out.println("Stop Recognition..");
                recognizer.stopRecognition();
            }
        }
```

but I am getting below exception at line  `while ((result = recognizer.getResult()) != null)` ;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NegativeArraySizeException
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.feature.LiveCMN.initMeansSums(LiveCMN.java:130)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.frontend.feature.LiveCMN.getData(LiveCMN.java:161)
```

please suggest me how to solve this.

Comment: Make sure that input file has proper format - 16khz 16bit mono PCM file.

Comment: It only work for this format????

Comment: Yes, in case you have different one you can resample using sox.

Comment: Getting same error for this file also test_mono_16000Hz_16bit_PCM.wav which has 16khz 16bit mono PCM format

Comment: sorry till now I tried to convert an audio file which has only music track that may be the reason for the error.

Answer (score 0):

This issue has been fixed in subversion in revision 12586.